# intel Fortran compiler flag to check for implicit conversion

Tags: intel-fortran

Which Intel Fortran compiler flag should I use to be warned about implicit conversions?

In gfortran, it is -Wconversion, which gives warnings like:
"Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(4) to INTEGER(4)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intel Fortran doesn't have a warning for that, which in general is behavior specified by the Fortran standard. Certainly that could be useful in some situations to alert you to possible issues. Intel Fortran does have an extension to do free converts between numeric and LOGICAL types, and this will be detected if you enable standards warnings (-std or /stand).